# Question about linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $D : F[t]n → F[t]n$ be the diﬀerentiation map. Let $f ∈
(F[t]n)^*$ be the functional assigning to each y(t) ∈ F[t]n the integral $\int\limits_0^1 y(t)dt.$
Compute the functional $D^*(f).$
Please help I do not know how to start this question.

Comment: Not knowing how to start a question usually reveals a deeper problem with understanding how to do rigorous mathematics as a whole. So, for starters: do you know the general definition of $D*(f)$ (by which I think you mean $D^*(f)$)?

Comment: Yes, you found EXACTLY what my problem is in answering this question. I do not know what the question is asking specifically. Firstly, it says D:F[t]n→F[t]n as a differentiation map which I think the prof should have written as D:F[t]n→F[t]n-1 (since differentiation on a polynomial will reduce its order by 1). Secondly, to answer your question, I think that D*(f) means dual basis of D acting on functional f. My question then is, how does a linear functional that is an element of D* act on  f which is an element of (F[t]n)*

Comment: Hint: For the meaning of $D^*(f)$, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_space#Transpose_of_a_linear_map.

Comment: Okay, you're getting somewhere! You're clarifying what you do and don't know, which is important. I'm guessing that $D^*$ represents, not a dual basis of something, but rather the dual of a map/operator. Being able to write down the definition of $D^*$ (in general and in this specific case) is very important for solving this problem.

Comment: Another comment: it is true that $D$ could be written as a map from $F[t]_n$ to $F[t]_{n-1}$; but it is also correct to write it as a map from $F[t]_n$ to $F[t]_n$. (I assume that $F[t]_n$ denotes the set of polynomials of degree *at most* $n$, not *exactly equal to* $n$; do you agree?) This is similar to saying that the map $x\mapsto x^2$ can be written as a map from $\Bbb R$ to $[0,\infty)$, but it's also correct to write it as a map from $\Bbb R$ to $\Bbb R$. Nothing says that all points in the codomain have to be hit by a map.

Comment: Thank you very much for commenting. However, I am still stuck with this problem. So if let that D*:(F[t]n)*→(F[t]n)*, then D*(f(y))=f(D(y)). Which will just be differentiation map on y then integrating it from 0 to 1. So does this mean that answer is a0+a1+a2+....+an, where ai=the coefficient of t^i?